# How to set width to ImageView in ListView for mutil screen

Tags: android

I have a ListView with an ImageView and TextView, I want to set the width of the image as 2/3 of the screen.

How do I create a custom ImageView to do this? This is what I've tried so far.

**Custom View**

```
public class CustomImageListView extends ImageView {
    public CustomImageListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        // Snap
        // to
        int width = MainActivity.width;
        int height = MainActivity.height;
        int w = width *2/5;
        int h = w *4/6;
        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        // setMeasuredDimension(ChoseImage.width, ChoseImage.height); // Snap to
        // //
        // width
    }

}
```

**The custom View XML**

```
<tuannt.tinmoi.custom.CustomImageListView
            android:id="@+id/ivAvater"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/nomage" />
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Comment: It used set width image but I want set width and height image.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a horizontal linear layout with WeightSum = 3 and inside it put another layout with with layout_weight = 1, the remaining portion will be of weight = 2, so you can put your imageView there. Refer below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
    style="@style/translucent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#88000000"
        android:id="@+id/sidebar"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- other views, with a total layout_weight of 2 -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a Custom View to achieve this. You can make use of the [layout_weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) attribute.

This would be your layout for every item in the ListView.

**item_in_listview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

The [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) attribute is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean).

> In a nutshell, layout_weight specifies how much of the extra space in
>   the layout to be allocated to the View.

Comment: but if I want set width/height = 6/4 how I do?